# Fetching Backbone Models from ExpressJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am having difficulty in creating a client-side Backbone model that upon initialization retrieves some XML from a ExpressJS server. When the Backbone model is created, an initialization function calls `model.fetch()` and passes in its model ID in the query string. The server should read the ID and return the correct XML.

This currently isn't working (code below), when I debug in my browser, I can see the network request appears to be correct, for example the request could be `/biomodels?id=BIOMD0000000001`, but the request stays pending when it is initiated from Backbone.

However, If I use my browser (Chrome), and go to `/biomodels?id=BIOMD0000000001` then the model correctly is retrieved.

Express server route handler:

```
/*global exports require*/
exports.getModel = function (req, res) {
    // Dependencies
    var biomodels = require('biomodels').BioModelsWSClient;
    // Get SBML From ID
    console.log('requested ID: ' + req.query.id)
    console.log(biomodels.getModelSBMLById(req.query.id, function (err, results) {
        console.log(err + results);
        res.send(err + results);
    }));
};
```

Backbone Model:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var BioModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            sbml: 'was not fetched',
            id: 'was not assigned'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            var modelId = this.id,
                modelSbml = this.sbml;
            this.fetch({
                data: {
                    id: modelId
                },
                type: 'GET',
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('error in GET: ' + textStatus + errorThrown);
                },
                url: 'biomodels',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    modelSbml = data;
                    console.log('loaded ' + modelSbml);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return BioModel;
});
```

Comment: I added your BioModel to one of my projects and just changed the url to one that the server was listening to and it got a response and loged the 'loaded' line.

Comment: Hm, I can't get to that point with my code, the request just stays pending. The response is sending an XML object, could it be a problem with the Accept request settings not being appropriate?

Comment: The response may be getting messed up because you are sending `err + response` back. If it is xml you are sending back, before sending the response, try setting this: `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");`.